# How do I go about unit testing with Entity Framework and Moq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, moq

I'm new to Moq, and wanting to use it like a backing store for data - but without touching the live database.

My setup is as follows:

- A UnitOfWork contains all repositories, and is used for data access throughout the application.
- A Repository represents a direct hook into a DbSet, provided by a DbContext.
- A DbContext contains all DbSets.

Here is my test so far:

```
        // ARRANGE
        var user = new User()
        {
            FirstName = "Some",
            LastName = "Guy",
            EmailAddress = "some.guy@mockymoqmoq.com",
        };

        var mockSet = new MockDbSet<User>();
        var mockContext = new Mock<WebAPIDbContext>();

        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<User>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        // ACT
        using (var uow = UnitOfWork.Create(mockContext.Object))
        {
            uow.UserRepository.Add(user);
            uow.SaveChanges();
        }

        // ASSERT
        mockSet.Verify(u => u.Add(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once());
```

My test seems to be successful, as it can verify that a user was added to the mock DbSet - but what I need to do is actually get that data back and perform further assertions on it (this is just an ad-hoc test).

Please advise, testing frameworks are doing my head in. Also, I have the option to move to other testing frameworks if they are easier to use.

Thank you.

**Update: Here is my working code.**

*Unit Test*

```
        // ARRANGE
        var user = new User()
        {
            FirstName = "Some",
            LastName = "Guy",
            EmailAddress = "some.guy@mockymoqmoq.com",
        };

        var mockSet = new MockDbSet<User>();
        var mockContext = new Mock<WebAPIDbContext>();

        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<User>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        // ACT
        using (var uow = UnitOfWork.Create(mockContext.Object))
        {
            uow.UserRepository.Add(user);
            uow.SaveChanges();
        }

        // ASSERT
        mockSet.Verify(u => u.Add(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once());

        // TODO: Further assertations can now take place by accessing mockSet.BackingStore.
    }
```

*MockDbSet*

```
class MockDbSet<TEntity> : Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> where TEntity : class
{
    public ICollection<TEntity> BackingStore { get; set; }

    public MockDbSet()
    {
        var queryable = (this.BackingStore ?? (this.BackingStore = new List<TEntity>())).AsQueryable();

        this.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
        this.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
        this.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        this.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());

        // Mock the insertion of entities
        this.Setup(e => e.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Returns((TEntity entity) =>
        {
            this.BackingStore.Add(entity);

            return entity;
        });

        // TODO: Other DbSet members can be mocked, such as Remove().
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code for the mock db set. You just need to create a collection to act as the backing store and mock the enumeration db set with the backing collection.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated my post. MockDbSet is untested, as I'm not quite sure how it all fits together. I'd doubt that the "queryable" variable works that way for a DbSet.

How would I go about creating a collection to act as the backing store by hooking into the mock DbSet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to create a collection to act as the backing store and mock the enumeration db set with the backing collection

```
public class MockDbSet<TEntity> : Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> where TEntity : class {
    public MockDbSet(List<TEntity> dataSource = null) {
        var data = (dataSource ?? new List<TEntity>());
        var queryable = data.AsQueryable();

        this.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
        this.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
        this.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        this.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
        //Mocking the insertion of entities
        this.Setup(_ => _.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Returns((TEntity arg) => {
            data.Add(arg);
            return arg;
        });

        //...the same can be done for other members like Remove
    }
}
```

So now you can use a list to hold the data

```
// ARRANGE
var dataSource = new List<User>(); //<-- this will hold data
var user = new User()
{
    FirstName = "Some",
    LastName = "Guy",
    EmailAddress = "some.guy@mockymoqmoq.com",
};

var mockSet = new MockDbSet<User>(dataSource);
var mockContext = new Mock<WebAPIDbContext>();

mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<User>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);

// ACT
using (var uow = UnitOfWork.Create(mockContext.Object))
{
    uow.UserRepository.Add(user);
    uow.SaveChanges();


    // ASSERT
    mockSet.Verify(u => u.Add(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once());
    Assert.IsTrue(dataSource.Contains(user)); //<-- shows mock actually added item
    Assert.IsTrue(uow.UserRepository.Any(u => u == user)); //<-- show you can actually query mock DbSet
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer, I found one syntax error when I tried to implement this using the latest Entity Framework on .Net 5, the method to setup adding an entity to the db set needs to be cast to EntityEntry like this:
   


```//Mocking the insertion of entities
Setup(_ => _.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Returns((TEntity arg) => {
 data.Add(arg);
 return arg.As<EntityEntry<TEntity>>();
});```